# Fluxion disconnecting both of my external and internal wifi cards

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle, raspberry-pi

I installed fluxion in raspberry pi so i can use it on the go. I mainly connect to my pi using ssh and vnc. I plugged an external wifi adapter to my PI to support monitor mode, but when I select my external wifi card on fluxion menu, it disconnects both internal and external cards.

I tried switching on monitor mode just in wlan1 and then running fluxion but it just asks me to select a card and after selecting my external card it disconnects both.

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is not managing well the Network Manager.

Fluxion is a good program by the way, but I can recommend to you to use [airgeddon](https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon). It is a similar software supporting a lot of attacks (wps, wep, different evil twins, wpa/2 cracking, etc.) and it is managing Network Manager in a controlled way detecting the version and acting based on it. It can be used in a Rpi as well.